# Configure Postman to call Neo4j API

Tags: neo4j, postman

I'm trying to configure Postman to test Neo4j API calls and am using this link which is the only thing I have found for help on this:

https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/a-lightweight-approach-to-testing-the-neo4j-rest-api-with-authentication/

Its an example of using a local instance rather than Aura

This is the URL I use when connecting via javascript and the Neo4j driver:

neo4j+s://4c7b0c8b.databases.neo4j.io

which gives me this error

```
GET neo4j+s://4c7b0c8b.databases.neo4j.io/
Error: Invalid protocol: neo4j+s:
Request Headers
Authorization: Basic bmVvNGo6STYzMGxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx0xfSFZURlUyNA==
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.31.3
Accept: */*
Postman-Token: 6e90541b-465a-4c64-926e-22af04d41258
Host: 4c7b0c8b.databases.neo4j.io
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
```

Evidently it does not like "neo4j+s:".

Is possible to get step by step instrucitons on configuring Postman to connect to Aura?

Thanks.

Comment: You should avoid sharing your actual Aura host address.

Comment: neo4j+s://4c7b0c8b.databases.neo4j.io/ is a Bolt URI. Bolt is a custom protocol over TCP, not HTTP. As pointed out already, Aura does not support Neo4j HTTP APIs yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article you cited was for neo4j 3.5.

Current versions of Aura [do not support the HTTP API](https://aura.support.neo4j.com/hc/en-us/articles/1500004216022-Does-Aura-support-an-HTTP-API-).

*And in any case, the [HTTP API](https://neo4j.com/docs/http-api/current/) uses the `http` or `https` protocols.*